# parse_ini_file() ignores include path

Tags: php

I'm having problems loading the parse_ini_file, currently I have registered a path in my include-path but there was an unexpected behavior parse_ini_file (didn't load)

(A little note: using phpunit to test, don't know if it affects the loading)

Example:

Path is: "C:/mydevelopworkspace/project/"

In that path there are well, php files, and an ini that specifies many folders, thing is, when I run parse_ini_file I get an error, but when I do:

```
 require_once 'Project/Config.ini';
```

It outputs the content, unlike parse_ini_file which doesn't really detects it =/ could anyone suggests me a workaround for this or an idea on where to look? Same thing happens with file_get_contents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Include paths" are the paths to search when doing an include, include_once, require or require_once.

All other functions that operate on files do not search the include path, including parse_ini_file.  You'll need to specify the file location yourself.

Comment: Figures... oh well, I think I can manage-got an idea that will resolve it, thanks for the info =)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the current working directory so that when you do your parse_ini_file call, the working directory is the right one.

```
<?php
$cDir = getcwd();

// Changing the directory to your custom one //
chdir('C:/mydevelopworkspace/');

$data = parse_ini_file('Project/Config.ini');

// Reseting the current working directory to the previous one //
chdir($cDir);
?>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could do that... Well, I got it fixed :) thumps up for you too. I have a Loader class that sets the library path into the include path, just created a getter to get the path set and combined it to do an absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP-Function called `stream_resolve_include_path()`. With this you are able to open files according to the PHP-Include-Path